# Zend coding not working in Sublime Text 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, zend-framework, sublimetext3

I am using Sublime Text 3 and i used emmet package for zend coding.It was working fine before install package "Sublime-Better-Completion-master". After install "Sublime-Better-Completion-master" auto complete package zend coding not working. Please tell me where is the problem.

Another question, Is any way to use bootstrap class auto completion in notepaid++?

Thanks.